# Trying to get the name of the current sheet in my vba formula

Tags: excel, vba

So i trying to get a cell from sheet 1 to equal a cell from the new sheets i will be creating and i keep running into problems, but i think i am close. Sheet 1 is set to my active sheet and I don't know how to change it either.

Range A1 in the below code is set to equal the current sheet name, so sheet 3.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=Sheets("Sheet2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Formula = "=" & Range("A1").Value & "!" & Range("B3").Address
```

Currently I have a message of Run time error  '1004'

Comment: 1) `Range("B3").Address` is `$B$3` so you can simplify there. 2) You need to get or set the name of the new sheet to use in your formula.

Comment: `.Formula = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$B$3"`

Comment: I would use ActiveSheet.Name, but as i have stated my active sheet is set to sheet 1 when the vba code starts and i do not know how to change it.

Comment: As soon as you add a sheet the new sheet becomes the active sheet.

Comment: A1 is set to equal the new sheet name on the respective sheet BigBen

Comment: I do not why it is still pulling the active sheet as sheet 1 then.

Comment: It works for me without issue, no matter what sheet is active when I start the code.  Make sure you are not setting `Sheet1` active after adding the new sheet.

Comment: What may cause sheet 1 to be set as my active sheet? Does select do it?

Comment: if you have any `.Select` or `.Activate` you should remove them.

Comment: Thanks Scott for all your help and patience.